# typescript dynamic assignment has a type error. I have multiple data that need to be retrieved from each other,

Tags: typescript

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: "xx" };
const obj2 = { a: 2, b: "3", d: "hello" };
for (const key in obj1) {
  const _key = key as keyof typeof obj1;
  obj1[_key] = obj2[_key];
}
```

x[_key] error

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFHo.png)

Is there any solution for this?

Correct circular assignment

Because the keys of the two objects are different, I need to extract some of the keys inside the obj.

Comment: Why don't you use `Object.assign`

Comment: Because the keys of the two objects are different, I need to extract some of the keys inside the obj.

Comment: ① Welcome to Stack Overflow! Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) ② Are you trying to copy just `a` and `b`?  If so then your code is incorrect at runtime and you should switch it to `const key in x`.  What you're doing right now is equivalent to `Object.assign()` so if that doesn't work for you then your code has a problem unrelated to the question you're asking.  You might want to [edit] so that only the problem you're asking about is present.

Comment: (see prev comment) ③ Once you resolve those, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8VR0m) meet your needs?  TS can't correlate unions so you need to use generics instead.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining (but again, please edit to deal with 1&2 above). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you. There may be some issues with my initial demo. I have updated the demo and copied the error description

Answer (score 0):

```js
import lodash from "lodash";

let obj1 = { a: 1, b: "xx" };
const obj2 = { a: 2, b: "3", d: "hello" };
const tmpObj3 = lodash.pick(obj2, Object.keys(obj1));
obj1 = { ...obj1, ...tmpObj3 };
```

Thank you all. I have resolved this issue